# Lower Shares from certain miners

Tags: bfgminer, raspberry-pi

I am currently using bfgminer 3.99.0 installed on a raspberry pi on top of raspbian.  I have 7 ant miner u2 miners plugged in split over 2 usb hubs.

Looking at the stats produced from bfgminer the shares seem to vary massively although they were all started at the same time.

[image]

I have also used mine peon and experience the same issue.  When I log into my pool the hash rate differs massively from the output of the miners.

As a test I loaded asteroid on my iMac and connected the miners, I don't know how to see the share rate on that but my hash rate from asteroid and the hash rate on the pool matched (very close).

So my question is why does the accepted rate differ between miners so much and also why does this cause a difference in hash rates and is there anything I can do about it.